# WordPress Functions PHP issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I use the following code, nothing actually gets linked to the page, except the random text at the bottom:

```
<?php

    function salt_scripts() {
        //global $wp_styles;
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela');


        // Loads main stylesheet
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-styles.css' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'salt_scripts' );

?>


LKDJFLSDKJFLSDKFJSLDKFJ WORK
```

I'm really at a loss at what else to try. I've been to dozens of sites and have stolen code bits from the default WordPress themes.

My folder structure is like this:

```
salt
    css
        bootstrap.css
        bootstrap-theme.min.css
        custom-styles.css
    img
    js

    style.css
    header.php
    index.php
    functions.php
```

This is what's in my header.php:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" data-offset="120">

<!-- Begin Main Nav-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="main-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="images/SaltSolutionsLogo.jpg" alt="SALT Solutions" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'About Us');">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#solutions" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Solutions');">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#casestudies" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Case Studies');">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resources" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Resources');">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#calculate" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Calculate');">Calculate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ourteam" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Our Team');">Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Blog');">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Main Navigation', 'click', 'Contact');">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social-media hidden">
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Social Media', 'click', 'Facebook');"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Social Media', 'click', 'Twitter');"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Social Media', 'click', 'GooglePLus');"><img src="images/googleplus.png" alt="Google+" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Social Media', 'click', 'LinkedIn');"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--End main-nav -->
```

Comment: Without functions.php where are you placing this code?

Comment: What do you mean? This code is in functions.php. If it wasn't in functions.php, I suppose it'd go in header.php or index.php?

Comment: @NathanDawson I can't get it to work no matter where I put this code. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I asked because you're not showing a functions.php inside your theme folder.

Comment: Please paste the contents of header.php in your question as well.

Comment: Woops, sorry. Yes. It's in there. Just forgot that one.

Comment: Do you have ```<?php wp_head(); ?>``` in your header.php between the <head> tags? You need a call to that function to output the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the top of your document which is why this isn't working.

Add the following to the top of `header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Much more could / should go here but this will get you started and fix your CSS loading issue.

Close off the HTML tag in `footer.php`

Before `</body>` in `footer.php` add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`

E.g.

```
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was <?php wp_head(); ?> that was what fix it. Thanks. I was trimming down the header.php to try to narrow down the problem. I added back all the doctype and meta information. Thanks.